# Why will my multi-threaded port scanner not detect open ports past a certain point? C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, vector

The code for my scanner is below. If I decide to check if only port 2220 is open on 176.9.9.172, it tells me that it is. However, when I run option 0 to check ALL the ports up to 10000, it only registers that port 22 and port  80 are open. It's multi-threaded and runs up to 4 threads at a time. It waits for the 4 threads to complete and then deletes them and resets the vector of threads to reduce memory issues. I'm not sure what's causing the problem.

**UPDATE** - I added a section of code after `myNetworkSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);` in the TestPortConnection() function, and as I ran it, I found that the socket creation failed after I scanned ports 1 - 1023. I realized that I forgot to close the ports if they failed to connect in some situations. I inserted the code to close them, and it works now!

```
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>

std::mutex bufferLock;

bool TestPortConnection(std::string ip, int port) {

    //creates a socket on your machine and connects to the port of the IP address specified
    struct sockaddr_in address;
    int myNetworkSocket = -1;

    address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    address.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(ip.c_str());
    address.sin_port = htons(port);

    myNetworkSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    fcntl(myNetworkSocket, F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK);

    connect(myNetworkSocket, (struct sockaddr *)&address, sizeof(address)); 

    //creates a file descriptor set and timeout interval
    fd_set fileDescriptorSet;
    struct timeval timeout;

    FD_ZERO(&fileDescriptorSet);
    FD_SET(myNetworkSocket, &fileDescriptorSet);
    timeout.tv_sec = 2;
    timeout.tv_usec = 0;

    int connectionResponse = select(myNetworkSocket + 1, NULL, &fileDescriptorSet, NULL, &timeout);
    if (connectionResponse == 1) {
        int socketError;
        socklen_t len = sizeof socketError;

        getsockopt(myNetworkSocket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_ERROR, &socketError, &len);

        if (socketError==0) {
            close(myNetworkSocket);
            return true;
        }
        else {
            close(myNetworkSocket);
            return false;
        }
    }
    else if (connectionResponse==0) {
      return false;
    }
    else if (connectionResponse==-1) {
      return false;
    }
    return false;
}

std::string GetHost() {
  std::string inputHost;

  std::cout << "Hostname/IP: ";
  std::getline(std::cin, inputHost);

  return inputHost;
}

void DisplayOptions() {
  std::cout << std::endl << "OPTIONS:" << std::endl;

  std::vector<std::string> optionDescriptions;

  optionDescriptions.push_back("Scan all ports");
  optionDescriptions.push_back("Scan for a specific port");
  optionDescriptions.push_back("Scan all common ports");

  for (int i = 0; i < optionDescriptions.size(); i++) {
    std::cout << "[" << i << "] " << optionDescriptions.at(i) << std::endl;
  }

  std::cout << std::endl;
}

int GetOption() {
  DisplayOptions();

  std::string optionToReturn;
  std::cout << "Option: ";
  std::getline(std::cin, optionToReturn);

  try {
    return std::stoi(optionToReturn);
  }
  catch (...) {
    return -1;
  }
}

void ThreadTask(std::vector<int>* bufferArg, std::string hostNameArg, int port) {
  if (TestPortConnection(hostNameArg, port)){
    bufferLock.lock();
    bufferArg->push_back(port);
    bufferLock.unlock();
  }
}

void ScanAllPorts(std::string hostNameArg) {
  
  std::vector<std::thread*> portTests;

  std::vector<int> buffer;

  int numOfTasks = 4;

  for (int i = 0; i < 575; i++) {
    for (int j = 1; j < numOfTasks+1; j++) {
      portTests.push_back(new std::thread(ThreadTask, &buffer, hostNameArg, (i*numOfTasks)+j));
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < numOfTasks; j++) {
      portTests.at(j)->join();
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < numOfTasks; j++) {
      delete portTests.at(j);
    }
    portTests = {};
  }

  //print out the list of all the open ports
  if (buffer.size()==0) {
    std::cout << "No open ports" << std::endl;
  }
  else {
    for (int i = 0; i < buffer.size(); i++) {
      std::cout << "Port " << buffer.at(i) << " is open!" << std::endl;
    }
  }

}

void ScanSpecificPort(std::string hostNameArg) {
  
  //get port
  int port;

  std::string portString;
  std::cout << "Port #: ";
  std::getline(std::cin, portString);

  try {
    port = std::stoi(portString);
  }
  catch (...) {
    std::cout << "Invalid port number." << std::endl;
    exit(0);
  }


  //test port number
  if (port<1||port>65535) {
    std::cout << "Invalid port number." << std::endl;
    exit(0);
  }


  //test connection
  if (TestPortConnection(hostNameArg, port)){
    std::cout << "Port " << port << " is open!" << std::endl;
  }
  else {
    std::cout << "Port " << port << " is closed." << std::endl;
  }
}

void ScanCommonPorts(std::string hostNameArg) {

  //initialize list of common ports
  std::vector<int> commonPorts;
  commonPorts = {7, //Echo
    19, //Chargen
    20, //FTP Data Transfer
    21, //FTP Command Control
    22, //FTPS/SSH
    23, //Telnet
    25, //SMTP
    26, //SMTP
    42, //WINS Replication
    43, //WHOIS
    49, //TACACS
    53, //DNS service
    67, //DHCP
    68, //DHCP
    69, //TFTP
    70, //Gopher
    79, //Finger
    80, //HTTP
    88, //Kerberos
    102, //MS Exchange
    110, //POP3
    113, //Ident
    119, //NNTP (Usenet)
    123, //NTP
    135, //Microsoft RPC
    137, //NetBIOS
    138, //NetBIOS
    139, //NetBIOS
    143, //IMAP
    161, //SNMP
    162, //SNMP
    177, //XDMCP
    179, //BGP
    194, //IRC
    201, //AppleTalk
    264, //BGMP
    318, //TSP
    381, //HP Openview
    382, //HP Openview
    383, //HP Openview
    389, //LDAP
    411, //Direct Connect
    412, //Direct Connect
    443, //HTTPS
    445, //Microsoft DS
    464, //Kerberos
    465, //SMTP over SSL
    497, //Retrospect
    500, //ISAKMP
    512, //rexec
    513, //rlogin
    514, //syslog
    515, //LPD/LPR
    520, //RIP
    521, //RIPng (IPv6)
    540, //UUCP
    554, //RTSP
    546, //DHCPv6
    547, //DHCPv6
    560, //rmonitor
    563, //NNTP over SSL
    587, //SMTP SSL
    591, //FileMaker
    593, //Microsoft DCOM
    631, //Internet Printing Protocol
    636, //LDAP over SSL
    639, //MSDP (PIM)
    646, //LDP (MPLS)
    691, //MS Exchange
    860, //iSCSI
    873, //rsync
    902, //VMware Server
    989, //FTP over SSL
    990, //FTP over SSL
    993, //IMAP SSL
    995, //POP3 SSL
    1025, //Microsoft RPC
    1026, //Windows Messenger
    1027, //Windows Messenger
    1028, //Windows Messenger
    1029, //Windows Messenger
    1080, //SOCKS Proxy
    1080, //MyDoom
    1194, //OpenVPN
    1214, //Kazaa
    1241, //Nessus
    1311, //Dell OpenManage
    1337, //WASTE
    1433, //Microsoft SQL
    1434, //Microsoft SQL
    1512, //WINS
    1589, //Cisco VQP
    1701, //L2TP
    1723, //MS PPTP
    1725, //Steam
    1741, //CiscoWorks 2000
    1755, //MS Media Server
    1812, //RADIUS
    1813, //RADIUS
    1863, //MSN
    1985, //Cisco HSRP
    2000, //Cisco SCCP
    2002, //Cisco ACS
    2049, //NFS
    2077, //WebDAV/WebDisk
    2078, //WebDAV/WebDisk SSL
    2082, //cPanel
    2083, //cPanel SSL
    2086, //WHM
    2087, //WHM SSL
    2095, //Webmail
    2096, //Webmail SSL
    2100, //Oracle XDB
    2220,
    2222, //DirectAdmin
    2302, //Halo
    2483, //Oracle DB
    2484, //Oracle DB
    2745, //Bagle.H
    2967, //Symantec AV
    3050, //Interbase DB
    3074, //XBOX Live
    3124, //HTTP Proxy
    3127, //MyDoom
    3128, //HTTP Proxy
    3222, //GLBP
    3260, //iSCSI Target
    3306, //MySQL
    3389, //Terminal Server
    3689, //iTunes
    3690, //Subversion
    3724, //World of Warcraft
    3784, //Ventrilo
    3785, //Ventrilo
    4333, //mSQL
    4444, //Blaster
    4664, //Google Desktop
    4672, //eMule
    4899, //- Radmin
    5000, //UPnP
    5001, //Slingbox
    5001, //iperf
    5004, //RTP
    5005, //RTP
    5050, //Yahoo! Messenger
    5060, //SIP
    5190, //AIM/ICQ
    5222, //XMPP/Jabber
    5223, //XMPP/Jabber
    5432, //PostgreSQL
    5500, //VNC Server
    5554, //Sasser
    5631, //pcAnywhere
    5632, //pcAnywhere
    5800, //VNC over HTTP
    5900, //VNC Server
    5901, //VNC Server
    5902, //VNC Server
    5903, //VNC Server
    5904, //VNC Server
    5905, //VNC Server
    5906, //VNC Server
    5907, //VNC Server
    5908, //VNC Server
    5909, //VNC Server
    5910, //VNC Server
    5911, //VNC Server
    5912, //VNC Server
    5913, //VNC Server
    5914, //VNC Server
    5915, //VNC Server
    5916, //VNC Server
    5917, //VNC Server
    5918, //VNC Server
    5919, //VNC Server
    5920, //VNC Server
    5921, //VNC Server
    5922, //VNC Server
    5923, //VNC Server
    5924, //VNC Server
    5925, //VNC Server
    5926, //VNC Server
    5927, //VNC Server
    5928, //VNC Server
    5929, //VNC Server
    5930, //VNC Server
    5931, //VNC Server
    5932, //VNC Server
    5933, //VNC Server
    5934, //VNC Server
    5935, //VNC Server
    5936, //VNC Server
    5937, //VNC Server
    5938, //VNC Server
    5939, //VNC Server
    5940, //VNC Server
    5941, //VNC Server
    5942, //VNC Server
    5943, //VNC Server
    5944, //VNC Server
    5945, //VNC Server
    5946, //VNC Server
    5947, //VNC Server
    5948, //VNC Server
    5949, //VNC Server
    5950, //VNC Server
    5951, //VNC Server
    5952, //VNC Server
    5953, //VNC Server
    5954, //VNC Server
    5955, //VNC Server
    5956, //VNC Server
    5957, //VNC Server
    5958, //VNC Server
    5959, //VNC Server
    5960, //VNC Server
    5961, //VNC Server
    5962, //VNC Server
    5963, //VNC Server
    5964, //VNC Server
    5965, //VNC Server
    5966, //VNC Server
    5967, //VNC Server
    5968, //VNC Server
    5969, //VNC Server
    5970, //VNC Server
    5971, //VNC Server
    5972, //VNC Server
    5973, //VNC Server
    5974, //VNC Server
    5975, //VNC Server
    5976, //VNC Server
    5977, //VNC Server
    5978, //VNC Server
    5979, //VNC Server
    5980, //VNC Server
    5981, //VNC Server
    5982, //VNC Server
    5983, //VNC Server
    5984, //VNC Server
    5985, //VNC Server
    5986, //VNC Server
    5987, //VNC Server
    5988, //VNC Server
    5989, //VNC Server
    5990, //VNC Server
    5991, //VNC Server
    5992, //VNC Server
    5993, //VNC Server
    5994, //VNC Server
    5995, //VNC Server
    5996, //VNC Server
    5997, //VNC Server
    5998, //VNC Server
    5999, //VNC Server
    6000, //X11
    6001, //X11
    6112, //Battle.net
    6129, //DameWare
    6257, //WinMX
    6346, //Gnutella
    6347, //Gnutella
    6500, //GameSpy Arcade
    6566, //SANE
    6588, //AnalogX
    6665, //IRC
    6666, //IRC
    6667, //IRC
    6668, //IRC
    6669, //IRC
    6679, //IRC over SSL
    6697, //IRC over SSL
    6699, //Napster
    6881, //BitTorrent
    6891, //Windows Live
    6892, //Windows Live
    6893, //Windows Live
    6894, //Windows Live
    6895, //Windows Live
    6896, //Windows Live
    6897, //Windows Live
    6898, //Windows Live
    6899, //Windows Live
    6900, //Windows Live
    6901, //Windows Live
    6970, //Quicktime
    7212, //GhostSurf
    7648, //CU-SeeMe
    7649, //CU-SeeMe
    8000, //Internet Radio
    8080, //HTTP Proxy
    8086, //Kaspersky AV
    8087, //Kaspersky AV
    8118, //Privoxy
    8200, //VMware Server
    8500, //Adobe ColdFusion
    8767, //TeamSpeak
    8866, //Bagle.B
    9100, //HP JetDirect
    9101, //Bacula
    9102, //Bacula
    9103, //Bacula
    9119, //MXit
    9800, //WebDAV
    9898, //Dabber
    9988, //Rbot/Spybot
    9999, //Urchin
    10000, //Webmin
    10000, //BackupExec
    10113, //NetIQ
    10114, //NetIQ
    10115, //NetIQ
    10116, //NetIQ
    11371, //OpenPGP
    12035, //Second Life
    12036, //Second Life
    12345, //NetBus
    13720, //NetBackup
    13721, //NetBackup
    14567, //Battlefield
    15118, //Dipnet/Oddbob
    19226, //AdminSecure
    19638, //Ensim
    20000, //Usermin
    24800, //Synergy
    25999, //Xfire
    27015, //Half-Life
    27374, //Sub7
    28960, //Call of Duty
    31337}; //Back Orifice

  std::vector<std::thread> portTests;

  std::vector<int> buffer;

  //spawn threads
  for (int i = 0; i < commonPorts.size(); i++) {
    portTests.push_back(std::thread(ThreadTask, &buffer, hostNameArg, commonPorts.at(i)));
  }

  //wait for all threads to complete
  for (int i = 0; i < portTests.size(); i++) {
    portTests.at(i).join();
  }

  //print out the list of all the open ports
  if (buffer.size()==0) {
    std::cout << "No open ports" << std::endl;
  }
  else {
    for (int i = 0; i < buffer.size(); i++) {
      std::cout << "Port " << buffer.at(i) << " is open!" << std::endl;
    }
  }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    
    //get the hostname or IP address from user input
    std::string hostname;

    if (argc > 1) {
      hostname = argv[1];
    }
    else {
      hostname = GetHost();
    }

    //let them choose an option
    int option = -1;

    int count = 0; //if option selection fails, this disables reading the option from commandline
    
    while (option<0||option>2) {

      if (argc>=3&&count==0) {
        try {
          option = std::stoi(argv[3]);
        }
        catch (...) {
          option = -1;
        }
      }
      else {
        option = GetOption();
      }
      
      if (option==0) {
        ScanAllPorts(hostname);
      }
      else if (option==1) {
        ScanSpecificPort(hostname);
      }
      else if (option==2) {
        ScanCommonPorts(hostname);
      }
      else {
        std::cout << "Invalid option. Please try again." << std::endl;
        count++;
      }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: 1. You are leaking sockets in three out of five cases. 2. You are therefore running out of local ports. 3 You have no error-checking on the `connect()` call. If you had, you would have discovered a bind error, which would have caused you to conclude that you are running out of local ports, and therefore that you are leaking sockets. 4. You are also missing error-checking on `socket()`, `fcntl()`, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are starting multiple execution threads, passing the pointer to the same `std::vector`, named "buffer" to all of these threads:

```
std::vector<int> buffer;

portTests.push_back(new std::thread(ThreadTask, &buffer, hostNameArg,
     (i*numOfTasks)+j));
```

Each execution thread, amongst other things, proceeds to merrily `push_back` its results into the same `buffer`:

```
void ThreadTask(std::vector<int>* bufferArg, std::string hostNameArg, int port) {
  if (TestPortConnection(hostNameArg, port)){
    bufferArg->push_back(port);
  }
}
```

This is undefined behavior. Neither `std::vector`, nor any other C++ library container, is thread-safe. This means that it cannot be directly accessed by multiple threads at the same time.

You must employ the services of a `std::mutex` to coordinate ***all*** access, to this vector, and to any other non-thread safe resource accessed concurrently by multiple execution threads.

Comment: I included a mutex in my code, but it still acts the same

Comment: @JustinA If you added the mutecx and it still acts the same why did you accept this answer? It's certainly correct as far as it goes but there are several other problems.

Comment: And why did you accept this answer if the real problem was not closing the sockets, as you were told elsewhere and not in this answer?